# Can't get this PostgreSQL query to run faster

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgis, query-performance

**I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6 with PostGIS 2.3.3**

I'm trying to make this rather critical query go faster (looking for users within 1000 meters of a location), but I'm having troubles setting up the right indexes.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

`users` are 200k rows, `locations` are 1200 rows, `user_push_tokens` are 155k rows

**users table:**

```
create table users
(
  id serial not null
    constraint users_pkey
      primary key,
  (an additional 20-ish columns),
  geo_point geometry(Point,4326)
);`

create unique index users_id
  on users (id);

create index users_geo_point_idx
  on users using gist(geo_point);
```

**user_push_tokens table:**

```
create table user_push_tokens
(
  user_id integer not null
    constraint push_tokens_user_id_fkey
      references users
        on delete cascade,
  push_token varchar(255) not null,
  push_provider varchar(64) not null,
  app varchar(64) default 'app'::character varying not null,
  id integer default nextval('user_push_tokens_id_seq'::regclass) not null
    constraint user_push_tokens_pkey
      primary key,
  active boolean default true not null,
);

create index trinity_unique_index
  on user_push_tokens (user_id, app, push_token);

create index user_push_tokens_token_fetch_idx
  on user_push_tokens (user_id, app, active);

create index user_id_index
  on user_push_tokens (user_id);
```

**locations table:**

```
create table locations
(
  id integer default nextval('locations_id_seq'::regclass) not null
    constraint locations_pkey
      primary key,
  (another 25 columns),
  geo_point geometry(Point,4326)
);

create unique index locations_id_key
  on locations (id);

create index locations_geo_point_idx
  on locations using gist(geo_point);
```

The query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT
    u.id AS user_id,
    upt.push_provider,
    upt.push_token
  FROM users u
    JOIN locations l ON l.id = 3896
    JOIN user_push_tokens upt
      ON upt.user_id = u.id AND upt.active = true AND upt.app = 'app'
  WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(u.geo_point, l.geo_point) <= 1000;
```

results in

```
Nested Loop  (cost=26087.06..63658.87 rows=30605 width=107) (actual time=353.304..887.371 rows=2498 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (_st_distance(geography(u.geo_point), geography(l.geo_point), '0'::double precision, false) <= '1000'::double precision)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 89539
  ->  Index Scan using locations_id_key on locations l  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.009..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = 3896)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=26086.78..39090.07 rows=91815 width=139) (actual time=352.437..657.228 rows=92037 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (upt.user_id = u.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on user_push_tokens upt  (cost=0.00..7162.82 rows=91815 width=107) (actual time=0.032..103.512 rows=92037 loops=1)
              Filter: (active AND ((app)::text = 'app'::text))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 62437
        ->  Hash  (cost=22114.46..22114.46 rows=195546 width=36) (actual time=352.199..352.199 rows=195589 loops=1)
              Buckets: 65536  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 3563kB
              ->  Seq Scan on users u  (cost=0.00..22114.46 rows=195546 width=36) (actual time=0.014..214.976 rows=195589 loops=1)
```

[More readable explain output](https://explain.depesz.com/s/DyYa)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What are the possible values of `app`?

Comment: you also cut off the times in your explain analyze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ST_DWithin

`ST_DistanceSphere(x,y)<t` cannot use your spatial index. `ST_DWithin` can, depending on the selectivity.  Instead use,

```
ST_DWithin(u.geo_point, l.geo_point, 1000);
```

Also, for testing purposes, you should remove the join to `user_push_tokens` and add it back once you get a better plan for the simpler query.

Comment: yes it'll use an index.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying. I finally found time to loop back around to this. I think you mean to use ST_DWithin in your second code block there. This small change made the query four times faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Schema changes

In addition to the mention by `jjanes`,

- **`varchar(x)`** : Don't use `varhcar(x)` in PostgreSQL, unless you *must* or otherwise have good reason to. Reviewing your schema, all of these should be `text`. It's faster.
- **`NOT NULL` with default strings**: What are the possible values here,

  ```
  app varchar(64) default 'app'::character varying not null,
  ```

  Your query has `app = 'app'::text` on the above, this is also not good

  ```
  active AND (app)::text = 'app'::text
  ```

  You probably want `nullable` and then just test if the value `IS NULL`
- **`geography` type**: also you probably don't want

  ```
  geometry(Point,4326)
  ```

  instead, use

  ```
  geography(Point,4326)
  ```

Comment: Hey thanks Evan! Using geography instead of geometry (duh, should have been obvious) cut the query time down even more (~150-200 ms to ~100-120ms). I will look at your other points as soon as I can. Thanks for answering!